# C# Orchard Session Destroyed EventHandler

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I want to check if the session was inactive for a specific time and then execute a work .

Is there any interface i can implement to control session events?

Comment: The general problem with this class of approach (and this is by no means limited to Orchard or even ASP.NET) is that there is no reliable way to determine why the session has been inactive, because session is a state mechanism built on a disconnected, stateless protocol. Pretty much nothing should depend on the session expiring. Can you explain in a little more detail what exactly you are trying to achieve and what the scenario is?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy what i mean't is not (getting why the session is inactive ) . i want just need to get the session Time and when the session terminated .

Comment: You can't and that information would be meaningless if you could.